# Magento 2 product image is visible in Magento admin, but not visible in frontend

Tags: magento, magento2

Magento 2 product image is visible in Magento admin, but not visible in frontend.

I have tried all these solutions but no luck.

Magento version (2.3.6)

- Solution 1 - 777 permissions to media folder: https://postimg.cc/fkxhSgP1
- Solution 2 - Ownership of the media folder: https://postimg.cc/rKjXQRMJ
- Solution 3 - Low PHP memory limit: https://postimg.cc/w1BKPxBd
- Solution 4 - already GD library is installed/configured: https://postimg.cc/87n8V8Ff
- Solution 5 - Set Global attribute scope for small_image, thumbnail, base_image: https://postimg.cc/Lqrrnz3H, https://postimg.cc/DWW9vCsj, https://postimg.cc/rKM21NXs
- Solution 6 -  Rename the original .htaccess file in media folder: https://postimg.cc/hQbWFfxK

Can anyone save me from here?

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of the frontend issue of image?

Comment: @MihirBangia
Frontend Preview : https://postimg.cc/xkK3Gts8

Answer (score 1):

Try running following command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Hope it helps and solve your issue..

Comment: Thanks for your time and try to find solutions but
Once I used this command it works for old products but when I upload new products again same issue. and yes I have more than 25k products uploaded so it's take a whole day or more. so it's not a permanent solution.